# Is already in c++11 or boost thread monitor?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Is already in c++11 or boost thread monitor ?
I need to monitor thread execution and when one fails for any reason I need to start again.
I am using  in c++11.

Comment: Just keep references to the exsting `std::thread` instances in your application maybe?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what constitutes a thread failure. If you mean it could exit, you can package it up:

Let's pretend we have a "long-running" task with a 25% chance of failing midway:

```
int my_processing_task() // this can randomly fail
{
    static const size_t iterations = 1ul << 6;
    static const size_t mtbf       = iterations << 2; // 25% chance of failure
    static auto odds = bind(uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, mtbf), mt19937(time(NULL)));

    for(size_t iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; ++iteration)
    {
        // long task
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));

        // that could fail
        if (odds() == 37) 
            throw my_failure();
    }

    // we succeeded!
    return 42;
}
```

If we want to keep running the task, regardless of whether it completed normally, or with an error, we can write a monitoring wrapper:

```
template <typename F> void monitor_task_loop(F f)
{
    while (!shutdown)
    try {
        f();
        ++completions;
    } catch (exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "handling: '" << e.what() << "'\n";
        ++failures;
    }
    std::cout << "shutdown requested\n";
}
```

In this case, I randomly thought it would be nice to count the number of regular completions, and the number of failures. The `shutdown` flag enables the thread to be shutdown:

```
auto timeout = async(launch::async, []{ this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3)); shutdown = true; });
monitor_task_loop(my_processing_task);
```

Will run the task montoring loop for ~3 seconds. A demonstration running three background threads monitoring our task is **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96be9d808e645599)**.

*Added [a c++03 version using Boost **Live On Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0811be6a0b486547).*

This version uses only standard c++11 features.

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

struct my_failure : virtual std::exception {
    char const* what() const noexcept { return "the thread failed randomly"; }
};

int my_processing_task() // this can randomly fail
{
    static const size_t iterations = 1ul << 4;
    static const size_t mtbf       = iterations << 2; // 25% chance of failure
    static auto odds = bind(uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, mtbf), mt19937(time(NULL)));

    for(size_t iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; ++iteration)
    {
        // long task
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));

        // that could fail
        if (odds() == 37) 
            throw my_failure();
    }

    // we succeeded!
    return 42;
}

std::atomic_bool shutdown(false);
std::atomic_size_t failures(0), completions(0);

template <typename F> void monitor_task_loop(F f)
{
    while (!shutdown)
    try {
        f();
        ++completions;
    } catch (exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << "handling: '" << e.what() << "'\n";
        ++failures;
    }
    std::cout << "shutdown requested\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto monitor = [] { monitor_task_loop(my_processing_task); };
    thread t1(monitor), t2(monitor), t3(monitor);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
    shutdown = true;

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    std::cout << "completions: " << completions << ", failures: " << failures << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Added [a c++03 version using Boost **Live On Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0811be6a0b486547) for completeness